# Principal value from two different axis

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex

I have an integral where its limits of integration is from the imaginary axis to the real axis, specifically,

$$\int_{\pi i/2}^\infty \frac{dp}{\sinh(p/2) \sqrt{\cosh(p)}}$$

I want to evaluate this along the contour from $[\pi i/2,0]$ then $[0,\infty]$ (L-shaped contour). However, the integrand has a pole at $p=0$. Is there any way to use the principal value method to evaluate this integral?

If you evaluate `func[p]` near the pole from the imaginary axis and from the real axis, you will see that they diverge in the opposite direction (one positive one negative) albeit in different axes. I have tried for example at $p=10^{-4}$.

```
func[p_] := 1/(Sinh[p/2] Sqrt[Cosh[p]])

func[10^-4 I] // N
0. - 20000. I

func[10^-4] // N
20000.

NIntegrate[func[p], {p, Pi I/2, 0, 100}, Method -> PrincipalValue]

NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option.

-1.76275 + 3.14159 I
```

I only know the principal value method if evaluating on the same axes. However I still tried to use `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Meanwhile I found a direct way to solve your problem in one step: `NIntegrate[func[ p], {p, I Pi/2, 0 I, Infinity}, 
 Method -> "PrincipalValue"]  (*-1.76275 + 3.14159 I*)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**final version(corrected)**

Perhaps you could try to integrate along a path which excludes the singular point `p= 0+I 0`  (quarter-circle radius eps) :

```
int[eps_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[func[ p], {p, I Pi/2, I eps}] + 
NIntegrate[func[eps (Sin[\[CurlyPhi]] + I Cos[\[CurlyPhi]])] D[
 eps (Sin[\[CurlyPhi]] +I Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]), \[CurlyPhi]], {\[CurlyPhi], 0, Pi/2}] + 
NIntegrate[func[p], {p, eps, Infinity}]
```

The Limit `eps->0` gives the integral you're looking for.

```
Table[{10^-n, int[10^-n]}, {n, 1, 5}] // N
(*{{0.1, -1.76275 - 3.14159 I}, {0.01, -1.76275 -3.14159 I}, {0.001, -1.76275 - 3.14159 I}, {0.0001, -1.76275 -3.14159 I}, {0.00001, -1.76275 - 3.14159 I}}*)
```

**addendum**

Modification of the integration path confirms the result:

```
int[eps_?NumericQ] := { NIntegrate[func[ p], {p, I Pi/2, I eps}],
NIntegrate[func[z], {z, I eps, eps }]
, NIntegrate[func[p], {p, eps, Infinity} ]} // Total    

Table[{10^-n, int [10^-n ]}, {n, 8, 10}] // N // Simplify // Chop
(*{{1.*10^-8, -1.76275 - 3.14159 I}, {1.*10^-9, -1.76275 - 3.14159 I}, {1.*10^-10, -1.76275 - 3.14159 I}}*)
```

Comment: I have tried to use your code but replaced `Infinity` by some large number, say `10^3`. It does not give any result. when doing `Limit[int[eps], eps -> 0]`. However, this integral with the corresponding small quarter-circle radius taken into account should produce a finite value, at least in principle. They don't converge I think is because the imaginary part and real part are still separate. The integral on the imaginary axis should produce a real value so that the appropriate divergence cancels.

Comment: If you notice the table that you produced, the real and imaginary part should cancel, at least in their values as `eps->0`.

Comment: An example is `NIntegrate[func[p], {p, 10^-2 I, Pi I/2}]` which produces a real value `11.9829 + 0. I`

Comment: @mathemania Because it's a numerically definition of  `int[eps]` `Limit[int[eps], eps -> 0]` cannot work.

Comment: @mathemania No the values mustn't cancel .  The integral along the imaginary axis gives an imaginary value, the integral along the real axis evaluates real.

Comment: What's causing the imaginary values is the quarter-circle radius, if I can just calculate that by hand, I get $-\pi i$ where the residue of `func[p]` at `p=0` is 2. Removing the quarter-circle radius contribution in the `NIntegrate` you wrote should produce a real value, right?

Comment: How  did you calculate the integral along the quarter-circle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127890/discussion-between-ulrich-neumann-and-mathemania).

Comment: It is just $i (\theta_2 - \theta_1) \mathcal{Residue}(f(p_0))$ where $p_0$ is a pole.