# Calculating Residue with NIntegrate fails

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Trying to answer this interesting question [Principal value from two different axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251431/principal-value-from-two-different-axis) I observed a problem using `Nintegrate`:

The function `func[p_] := 1/(Sinh[p/2] Sqrt[Cosh[p]])` has a pol at `p==0`.

The residue of this point evaluates to

```
Residue[func[z], {z, 0}] (*2*)
Limit[func[z] z, z -> 0] (*2*)
```

The result might be confirmed by integrating along a path in the complex plane which contains the pol. For example integrating along a square path

```
NIntegrate[func[z], {z, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}]/(2 Pi I) (*2*)
```

evaluates correct value , whereas integrating along a circle

```
NIntegrate[func[ Exp[I \[CurlyPhi] ]]/(2 Pi I), {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}]  (*~0*)
```

gives a message `NIntegrate failed to converge...`  and a wrong result `0`!

What's wrong with this last integration?

How to modify to get the correct result?

Thanks!

Comment: Alternate way (equivalent to `Method -> "Trapezoidal"`: `With[{n = 64},
 First@Fourier[
    Table[
     func[Exp[I \[CurlyPhi]]]*Exp[I \[CurlyPhi]], {\[CurlyPhi], 
      Most@Subdivide[0., 2 Pi, n]}]
    ]/Sqrt[n]
 ]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for this nice answer. Amazingly this "simple" method evaluates the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the derivative (see Residue of monomial [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis))):

```
NIntegrate[func[Exp[I \[CurlyPhi]]]/(2 Pi I)*I*Exp[I \[CurlyPhi]], {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> `1.99993 - 1.11022*10^-16 I`

Comment: I assumed the residum theorem in its common form. Why the derivative?

Comment: Additionally see "For continuous functions" in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration).

Comment: I'm still convinced that  the simple residuum definition (without the derivative) is the commonly accepted form of the residuum theorem. Thanks for your effort..

Comment: When you change variable, you need to include a derivative term to account for the fact that `dz!=d[\CurlyPhi]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann user64494 means the last formula in the wiki section. The derivative is what you get when you substitute $z=e^{i\phi}$ into the $dz$ of the contour integral $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz$. BTW, `Method -> "Trapezoidal"` numerical convergence properties than `"GlobalAdaptive"` on this sort of integral (see [Trefethen & Weideman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/130932132)).

Comment: I have had in mind $\gamma'(t)$. In your case $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$.  Hope I  (and textbooks )  am clear now.

Comment: I got it, thanks again!